# Code Behind JavaScript alert with redirecting

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, redirect, alert

How do I make my JavaScript in code behind work when I redirect to another page after? I have a asp button control and when I click that button I want to alert, then navigate to another page. When I have a `Response.Redirect` in my code (before or after the JS code), none of the 8 tries work. When I comment that redirect out, a few (2,7 & 8) work.

```
//Try one
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "test", "alert('test1');", true);

//Try two
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "test", "test2");

//Try three
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "alertMessage()", true);

//Try four
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "alertMessage()", true);

//Try five
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "javascript: alertMessage(); ", true);

//Try six
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "<script>alert('test4')</script>");

//Try seven
Response.Write("<script>alert('test5');</script>");

//Try eight
string script = "alert('test6')";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "CallMyString", script, true);

response.redirect("pageUrlHere");
//With this code above, none of the js functions (alerts) work

//response.redirect("pageUrlHere");
//With this commented out, try 2, 7 and 8 work.
```

JS function:

```
function alertMessage() {
    alert('test3');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"redirect",
"alert('test 9'); window.location='" + 
Request.ApplicationPath + "/anotherpage.aspx';",true);
```

Comment: Small change, a slash is needed before the page name `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"redirect",
"alert('test 9'); window.location='" + 
Request.ApplicationPath + "/anotherpage.aspx';",true);`

Answer (score 4):

Try this it will display alert and navigate
 It make it in separate method just to reuse again.

```
    public void ShowAlertAndNavigate(string msg , string destination)
    {
        string alert_redirect_Script = string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">
                                       alert('{0}');
                                        window.location.href = destination;
                                       </script>", msg);
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alertredirectscript",   alert_redirect_Script, false);
    }
```